Can I automatically update versions in GCP's Workspace Marketplace for App Script Add-Ons?
I'm looking into automating some of the deployments for some add-ons we have for the Google Workspace (specifically, Google Docs), and according to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on):
If you’re updating an Editor Add-on, update the version number
on the App Configuration page of the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK.

I cannot imagine there is no way of doing that automatically and all the extensions in the marketplace are doing manual updates of the versions.
Is there a way that I might be missing of updating the version of the add-on?
The Marketplace REST reference (https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest) doesn't show any methods to do this, so it tells me there is no way of doing it with an API or gcloud command.
Ideally, I would be looking to automate the entire lifecycle. I know I can create deployments and versions using CLASP (https://github.com/google/clasp), but I'm still missing the last bit of the lifecycle where I could deploy a new version automatically.
